# In Elixir/Phoenix/Ecto, how can I create a fixture with modified timestamp values for testing?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to be able to create a test data with custom `inserted_at` value for testing. Is this possible? Ideally it should be flexible so I can adjust the date to the test I want to write.

I've search the internet, ask the LLMs but no luck.

Comment: If you insert data using your changeset, the timestamps are going to be set for you. However, you can insert data directly by using `Repo.insert(%YourStruct{inserted_at: ~N[2020-01-01 00:00:00]})` with whatever naive datetime you want. You can also use something like [ex_machina](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_machina/readme.html#content) to accomplish it quite easily

Comment: Thank you. I will `Repo.insert` directly.